# Finding specific values in from a csv dataframe cell in json format

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a movie dataframe with a column 'cast'. The first 'cast' column for a certain movie looks like this:

```
[{'cast_id': 42, 'character': 'Ted the Bellhop', 'id': 3129, 'name': 'Tim Roth'},
 {'cast_id': 31, 'character': 'Man', 'id': 3131, 'name': 'Antonio Banderas'}, 
 {'cast_id': 29, 'character': 'Angela','id': 3130, 'name': 'Jennifer Beals'}]
```

My question is - how do I use `pandas.apply` to sort out this value which looks to be in a JSON format. I want to sort this value by finding all the 'characters' so i want my result to look like:

```
['Ted the Bellhop', 'Man', 'Angela']
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you need to use `pandas.DataFrame.apply()`?

My suggestion would be to turn the JSON into a DataFrame:

```
json = [{'cast_id': 42, 'character': 'Ted the Bellhop', 'id': 3129, 'name': 'Tim Roth'},
         {'cast_id': 31, 'character': 'Man','id': 3131, 'name': 'Antonio Banderas'},
         {'cast_id': 29, 'character': 'Angela','id': 3130, 'name': 'Jennifer Beals'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(json)
```

Then use [.loc()](https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-loc.php) and [.to_list()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html):

```
df.loc[:,'character'].to_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by using only map function too.

```py
cast = [
    {
        "cast_id":42,
        "character":"Ted the Bellhop",
        "id":3129,
        "name":"Tim Roth"
    },
    {
        "cast_id":31,
        "character":"Man",
        "id":3131,
        "name":"Antonio Banderas"
    },
    {
        "cast_id":29,
        "character":"Angela",
        "id":3130,
        "name":"Jennifer Beals"
    }
]
output = list(map(lambda x: x['character'], cast))
```